# Error: "mcrypt_decrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize"

Tags: php, mcrypt

I've looked elsewhere at the same error but not found anyone having the same problem as me.

I am submitting a form from `contactEdit.hbs` (Handlebars) which is injected into the `contact.php` page, the form then POSTS to `addcontact.php`.

**(**`contact.php` [**INJECT**]=> `contactEdit.hbs` [**POST**]=> `addcontact.php`**)**

`addcontact.php` uses mcrypt, shown below.

```
define('IV_SIZE', mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));

function encrypt ($key, $payload) {
  $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(IV_SIZE, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
  $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $payload, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
  $combo = $iv . $crypt;
  $garble = base64_encode($iv . $crypt);
  return $garble;
}

function decrypt ($key, $garble) {
  $combo = base64_decode($garble);
  $iv = substr($combo, 0, IV_SIZE);
  $crypt = substr($combo, IV_SIZE, strlen($combo));
  $payload = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $crypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
  return $payload;
}

$key = "mysupersafeandsecretkeythatialmostforgottoremovewhenpostingthis";
```

After this, I encrypt the data submitted from the form on the previous page (`contactEdit.hbs`) and store the values in my database, example of the encryption below

```
// ENCRYPTION
if(!empty($nationality)){
$nationality = encrypt($key, $nationality);
}
if(!empty($landline)){
$landline = encrypt($key, $landline);
}
if(!empty($mobile)){
$mobile = encrypt($key, $mobile);
}
if(!empty($email)){
$email = encrypt($key, $email);
}
if(!empty($nationalid)){
$nationalid = encrypt($key, $nationalid);
}
if(!empty($passport)){
$passport = encrypt($key, $passport);
}
if(!empty($dob)){
$dob = encrypt($key, $dob);
}
```

When **ALL** of the input boxes are filled out on the form and submitted, it works perfectly... Everything is posted to the database and we are returned to the `contacts.php` page by a simple header redirect at the end of the script (I also store the values in a .json array, which works fine!)

**NOW** here's the problem. When only a couple (or none) of the input boxes are filled out and we try to submit the form, I receive the following error:

`mcrypt_decrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize in addcontact.php on line 23`

Here's line 23:

`$payload = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $crypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);`

If anything was filled out on the form, it is still encrypted and posted to the database successfully, along with being saved to the .json file still.

So why do I get this error, everything still seems to work fine? The only problem is that as a result of this error, `addcontact.php` will not execute the header redirect (`header('Location: contacts.php');`) at the end of the script, this comes with its own error:

`:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at addcontact.php:23) in addcontact.php on line 193`

Help appreciated, if I've not been clear enough then feel free to ask :-)

Comment: The message shows a error generated by `mcrypt_decrypt()`, but the example code you posted doesn't call your `decrypt()` function anywhere.  How is it being called?

Comment: What PHP version are you using? I get an error because with php 5.6 I get the following error: "mcrypt_encrypt(): Key of size 63 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of sizes 16, 24 or 32 supported."

Comment: David, thanks to your comment I just solved the problem myself. As you see in my example above I am checking whether the variable is empty before encrypting it (`!empty($variable)`). I had not done the same when decrypting. Oops, I feel stupid!

Comment: Tchoupi, just for confirmation anyway I am using 5.4 with a compatibility patch to add support for mcrypt.

Comment: Using #defines for code has not been a best practice for a couple of decades.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.